# changing language in datenumber

Tags: languages, datenumber

I'm trying to change the language in the `datenumber` package as described in the [manual](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/datenumber/doc.pdf) on page 3.
Unfortunately `datenumber` doesn't hook into the babel translation but comes with its own translation mechanism.
I tried to provide the `datenumberngerman.ldf` file but this doesn't solve the issue. I also tried german vs. ngerman.

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datenumber}
%\input{datenumberngerman.ldf}
\dateselectlanguage{ngerman}

\begin{document}

\setdate{2002}{1}{1}%
\thedatenumber
%Ergebnis: 73780

\setdatetoday\addtocounter{datenumber}{10}%
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
\dateselectlanguage{ngerman}
In 10 Tagen ist der \datedate

\end{document}
```

Comment: `datenumber` is a very old package by now and has no updates since 2001. Most likely, you should switch to `datetime2`, which has `babel` language support. Try `\usepackage[german]{datenumber}` -- that works for me

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That works! If you'd like, make that into an answer, I'll accept it, if not I will write the answer myself.

Comment: Go on ... I am no rep hunter and I don't need to answer any question I encounter here. Happy TeXing! But I think `datetime2` is the better way to go for your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the switch `\usepackage[german]{datenumber}` will change the format to German. For an alternative to `datenumber` which is last updated 2001, see `datetime2`. Kudos to  Christian Hupfer for the comment.